# Proof that $d/dtf(t)=X(f(t))$ where $X$ is a vector field, $X(x,y)=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$ has a solution.

Tags: real-analysis

Proof that $\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=X(f(t))$ where $X$ is a vector field, $X(x,y)=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$ has a solution $f$.

I've tried to use Picard-Lindölf. The problem is i can't show that $X(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous because it may even not be Lipschitz continuous in the first place? Then I tried to construct $f$ explicitly but the equations are ugly intervened which makes it difficult. Any ideas

Comment: A picture of the vector field should make it clear what the integral curves are. If not, eliminate $t$ and find $dy/dx$ on the integral curves. Then figure out how $t$ enters.

Comment: the solutoin is a hyperbola

Comment: No, most definitely not. Sketch the picture.

Comment: $(\sqrt(t),\sqrt(t))$ its a line

Comment: Lots of rays … yes. You are missing various constants.